# Can someone explain this line of Typescript Code?

Tags: typescript

Im looking for an explanation of the use of such syntax.
I wont bore with my interpretation.

Updated with improved questions :
Would const customClaims only have 1 attribute?
Does that `as { role? : string }` remove other attributes as well?
What if user custom claims has no role attribute?

```
const customClaims = (user.customClaims || {role: ""}) as { role?: string };
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I think im beginning to grasp it. I see now my question could have been worded better.

Comment: But for the sake of completing the question, would const customClaims only have 1 attribute? does that ``` as { role? : string } ``` remove other attributes as well? What if user custom claims has no role attribute?

Comment: Type assertion does not remove properties from an object. Types only exist in typescript. When it eventually compiled to javascript, regardless of what type an object is, it is still just an object. The object retains all of its properties unless you explicitly delete them.

Comment: If `user.customClaims` has no `role` but typed as `any` to bypass type check, you will later get an `undefined` when you try to access `customClaims.role`. If `user.customClaims` is explicitly typed, you will get a compiler error saying "Property 'role' is missing in type '...' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down.

---

`(user.customClaims || {role: ""})` is an expression that result in a value (let's call it ).

If `user.customClaims` is a true value, then  is `user.customClaims`. Otherwise  is `{role: ""}`

---

`as { role?: string }` tells TypeScript that  is a value which conforms to the type `{ role?: string }`.

It does not *alter* the value of  at all.

---

If  has extra properties then it keeps them, but TypeScript doesn't know about them.

Consider:

```js
const foo = { role: "a", value: { x: "y" } };
const bar = (foo || {role: ""}) as { role?: string };
console.log(bar);
```

`bar` has a `value` property so the output of this will be:

> { role: 'a', value: { x: 'y' } }

but if you change the last line to `console.log(bar.value);`  TypeScript will error with:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ role?: string | undefined; }'.

---

If  hasn't got a `role` property then it still doesn't. Since the type definition makes the `role` optional, then that isn't a problem.

If  has a `role` property but it isn't a string, TypeScript will believe the value is a string so you could get a runtime error.

Consider:

```js
const foo = { role: { x: "y" } } as unknown;
const bar = (foo || {role: ""}) as { role?: string };
console.log(bar.role?.charAt(0));
```

This will error at runtime because objects, unlike strings, don't have a `charAt` method.

(NB: In this simple example, TypeScript knows enough about the object assigned to `foo` that it can work out `as { role?: string }` is a mistake if I don't use `as unknown` first).